# How to adapt DTO (data transfer object) to my angular project?

Tags: c#, angular, dto

I need to know how to adapt C# DTO's to my Angular 6 project.

For example I have this DTO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TriageMedico.DTOs
{
    public class BaseDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to know how to use it, in order to generate/create a model, and therefore use it to send HTTP requests.

Comment: Please show what you have done, your code snippet

Comment: You could also look at: https://swagger.io Several clients I know use that to keep their .NET and Angular code DTO's in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an interface on typescript

```
export interface BaseDTO {
   id: number;
}
```

When you do the httpRequest to the backend you type the response as BaseDTO

`myService.subscribe( (response: BaseDTO) => { ... some code here...  } );`

I don't know which (the HttpClient or Angular itself) but it is smart enough to map the properties of your C# interface to the typescript. But you need to match the names.

Comment: Nice answer, usually http 1.1 requests and responses are text or a compressed blob of text, when the C# server sends the response it'll be plain text body formatted to json, form encoding, xml etc. HttpClient gets the response and parses the body and figuring out which to use (by using response's CONTENT TYPE header, which may or may not match the request's ACCEPT header).  A great read to demystify what's going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages